# Passing input value to another inputfield

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, input

I'm trying to take subscription payments and membership details
The sign-up flow is as follows:

PAGE 1 = Enter Card Details

     | 

     |

PAGE 2 = Enter Personal Details (NB. token from page 1 is required to submit this form)

     | 

     |

PAGE 3 = Verify Email address (This part works fine)

Page 1 is the point at which the "customer" enters in their card details. 
This gets sent to Stripe and assuming that there is no errors Stripe sends back a "token". 
Now I have the token, typically a hidden input field, but I have it showing just for my own benefit for the time being. 
If all is well at this point I use ajax to change the forms content to one with email address fields etc.

```
 // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="text" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and re-submit
    $('#content').load('https://www.mydomain.com/registration-text.html#content');

    }
```

After the forms content change to page 2 I can literally see the content of `<input type="text" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />` still at the bottom of the page.

But when I fill out the email fields etc and hit submit it doesn't get sent with the form. In fact the form is setup to not allow a submission without a value for stripeToken, so at least that works.
Just wondering if anyone would have any idea as to a solution? Or even the potential source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The input must be in between the `form` tags, if you are saying that the `input` is located at the bottom of the page, so there is a chance that you have it outside your `form` tags (Just making a guess). *Please note that only the inputs inside the form tags are submitted to the next page*

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. It's still inside the form, I've dev tools running and I can see it in the element view.